# Django : Increase variable in the model

Tags: python, django, model

I have this model:

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    score_question_viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def increase_score_question_viewed(self):
        print("After: " + self.score_question_viewed)
        self.score_question_viewed += 10
        print("Before: " + self.score_question_viewed)
```

When I call `increase_score_question_viewed()` I see in my terminal:

```
Before: 0
After: 10
```

But after, when I do `profil.score_question_viewed` I see `0`

The value has not been saved...

Do you know how can I save my value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `self.save()` to save changes in DB:

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    score_question_viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def increase_score_question_viewed(self):
        print("After: " + self.score_question_viewed)
        self.score_question_viewed += 10
        print("Before: " + self.score_question_viewed)
        self.save()
```

Comment: Thank I tried `self.score_question_viewed.save()` but it didn't work aha !